# How do I unhide the window menu?

Tags: compiz, window, ubuntu-studio

I accidentally hid the window menu in Ubuntu Studio 18.04 by using view > hide.  I have compiz installed.  How do I unhide it?  I can't see any obvious way, right clicking on the toolbar doesn't have an option, have restarted compiz, looked in its Window Decoration settings and can't see any setting in dconf editor.

[image]

Comment: if all you did is hide it: rightclick at the toolsbar

Comment: @Rinzwind forget to mention that was the first thing I tried.  I've updated the question's image to show the options I have when I right click.

Comment: And is it still PCManFM you've shown? And is only PCManFM affected?

Comment: @DKBose no ignore that old image. That was just from the web to illustrate what menu I meant - the new image is an actual screenshot.  All system folders have been affected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually one of the following can be used:

- Some programs use <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>M</kbd> to show and hide the menubar.
- Many programs have a toolbar (not titlebar) context menu item to control menubar visibility.

  [image: context]
- Some programs show a hamburger menu on the toolbar (usually on the far right) when the menubar is hidden.

  [image: hamburger]